# How can I resolve XML Parsing Error: not well-formedLocation?

Tags: javascript, html, ajax, web-services

On load of my page I execute this function

```
function getConnection() {
    $.ajax({
        type: "GET",
        url: "../webservice/anonymous_PS.asmx/Get",
        data: { "PSname": "LISTE_CONNEXTION" },
        async : false ,
        success: function (response) {

            var data = response.getElementsByTagName("NewDataSet")[0]

            for (let i = 0; i < data.children.length; i++) {

                var c1Nb = $(data.children[i]).find('c1').text()
                var c2Nb = $(data.children[i]).find('c2').text()
                var c1 = document.getElementById("cs" + c1Nb)
                var c2 = document.getElementById("cs" + c2Nb)
                var line = $("#l_" + c1Nb + "_" + c2Nb)

            }

        }
    })

}
```

But when I do that I have this error on Firefox :

> XML Parsing Error: not well-formed
> Location:
> Line Number 1, Column 131:

and on chrome sometimes I have this error :

> devtools was disconnected from the page

How can I resolve my issue ?

Answer (score 0):

Try parsing your response, you can use `$.parseXML(response)` if you want to parse your response to xml or `$.parseHTML(response)` if you want to parse your response to html.

Once the parsing is done then your `getElementsByTagName("NewDataSet")[0]` will work and you will not get any error.

The final code will look something like:

```
var parsedResponse = $.parseXML(response);
var data = parsedResponse.getElementsByTagName("NewDataSet")[0];
```